# How the website transitions is achieved?

Tags: muse

im wondering how to achive this looks using adobe muse, is it possible?
[mistolin.pt](http://www.mistolin.pt)

or how is this effects even achieved?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about adobe muse, but I looked at the web page in the question, it is complete html and css 3, perhaps some JavaScript.

At a basic level, the mouse over events are used to animate the columns and to hide and display the content. Opacity is used to cover the background with the color.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i meant how can i duplicate this, if i wanted to use something like that?

Comment: Perhaps you could use Chrome development tools and look at the markup and style sheets on that site.